# Error marshalling JaxbXmlPart /word/document.xml

Tags: tomcat, docx4j, grizzly

I have an issue with the saving of a docx4j document to an OutputStream and I´m not sure how I should debug it.

I'm using 8.3.8 for both docx4j-ImportXHTML and docx4j for java 8.

In general I´m parsing an html document to docx4j and saving it to an OutputStream, i.e.

```
WordprocessingMLPackage docx = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
DocumentPart docPart = docx.getMainDocumentPart();
docPart.getContent().addAll(new XHTMLImporterImpl(docx).convert(htmlString, null));
docx.save(myOutputStream);.
```

Not alwasy, this process crashes while someothers it works fine. So I can't reproduce it always.

I have logged out org.docx4j.openpackaging, since there seems to be the error, but I'm not sure how to fix it. The logs give the following result:

```
2022-07-25 13:22:45 [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] | [514b616a-9211-4aae-a60a-affe61ff3d2f SuperUser user ]                                                   | DEBUG in org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.stores.ZipPartStore -> marshalling /word/document.xml 
2022-07-25 13:22:45 [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] | [514b616a-9211-4aae-a60a-affe61ff3d2f SuperUser user ]                                                   | DEBUG in org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.JaxbXmlPart -> marshalling org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart 
2022-07-25 13:22:45 [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] | [514b616a-9211-4aae-a60a-affe61ff3d2f SuperUser user ]                                                   | DEBUG in org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.JaxbXmlPart -> Marshalling to org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream 
2022-07-25 13:22:45 [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] | [514b616a-9211-4aae-a60a-affe61ff3d2f SuperUser user ]                                                   | DEBUG in org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part -> package name: null 
2022-07-25 13:22:45 [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] | [514b616a-9211-4aae-a60a-affe61ff3d2f SuperUser user ]                                                   | DEBUG in org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part -> package name: null 
2022-07-25 13:22:45 [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] | [514b616a-9211-4aae-a60a-affe61ff3d2f SuperUser user ]                                                   | ERROR in org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Save -> Error marshalling JaxbXmlPart /word/document.xml 
org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Error marshalling JaxbXmlPart /word/document.xml
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.stores.ZipPartStore.saveJaxbXmlPart(ZipPartStore.java:394)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Save.saveRawXmlPart(Save.java:289)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Save.savePart(Save.java:436)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Save.addPartsFromRelationships(Save.java:399)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Save.save(Save.java:193)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.save(OpcPackage.java:799)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.save(OpcPackage.java:729)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.save(OpcPackage.java:717)
    at myClass.save2Docx(MyClass.java:69)
    ...
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: null
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.JaxbXmlPart.marshal(JaxbXmlPart.java:937)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.JaxbXmlPart.marshal(JaxbXmlPart.java:748)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.stores.ZipPartStore.saveJaxbXmlPart(ZipPartStore.java:337)
    ... 89 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException: null
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:303)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:226)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:80)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.JaxbXmlPart.marshal(JaxbXmlPart.java:865)
    ... 91 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection is closed
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.assertOpen(NIOConnection.java:445)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:677)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:336)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:323)
    ...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    ...
```

While debugging on docx.save(myOutputStream); it shows me an exception:

```
org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Problem saving part /word/document.xml
Failed to add parts from relationships of /
```

I'm not sure how to approach it in order to solve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you capture the htmlString associated with a failure?  What version of Tomcat?  Can you reproduce outside of Tomcat?

Comment: And do you know what is happening at the client end at the time.  For example, could the user have closed the browser?

Comment: Yes...the htmlString seems to be ok and I can't associate it currently with the failure. As I mentioned, at the beginning of the payara server it fails and after 2-3 requests of the service it starts working. I cannot reproduce it outside the server. I'm using Payara 4.1.2.174 (build 192). Furthermore, I'm doing the request directly from Postman, but doing it from the browser it gives similar results

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it works, but I'm writing in case somebody else has the same issue.

I had the following in my code:

```
        StreamingOutput myOutput = out -> generateDocx(htmlString, out);
```

and changed it to:

```
StreamingOutput myOutput = new StreamingOutput() {
                @Override
                public void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                    generateDocx(htmlString, outputStream);
                }
            };
```

This code is on top of osgi framework, and for some reason the lambda expression close the connection...not sure why it happens.